# Converting base64 String to image in Android

Tags: android, image, base64

Is there any way that I can convert a base64 String to image in Android? I am receiving this base64 String in a xml from the server connected through socket.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a image into Base64 string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/ or any other example that converts base64 strings to byte-arrays, and then use the `ImageIcon(byte[] imageData)` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There are now [Base64](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) utilities in Android, but they only became available with Android OS 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

After failing to get any solutions (even on Stackoverflow), I built a plugin that converts Base64 PNG Strings to files  which I shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388018/phonegap-plugin-to-convert-base64-string-to-a-png-image-in-android-solved/11388019#11388019).
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert **base64** string to the image file (for example **.png** etc.) and save it to some folder you can use this code:

```
byte[] btDataFile = Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT);
String fileName = YOUR_FILE_NAME + ".png";
try {

  File folder = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir("") + /PathToFile);
  if(!folder.exists()){
    folder.mkdirs();
  }

  File myFile = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath(), fileName);
  myFile.createNewFile();

  FileOutputStream osf = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
  osf.write(btDataFile);
  osf.flush();
  osf.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And make sure you have given the following required permission in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```