# convert Base64 string to image in android

Tags: android

In an android application we are receiving a byte64 string.I need to convert these strings to images.
I tried getting it but couldnot find any.
Please let me know your valuable suggestions

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a image into Base64 string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string)

Comment: Please see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38714106/1225669

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for a week. So I built a phonegap plugin for Andriod which i shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388018/phonegap-plugin-to-convert-base64-string-to-a-png-image-in-android-solved/11388019#11388019).

Hope that helps. :)