# How can I convert an image into a Base64 string?

Tags: android, base64

What is the code to transform an image (maximum of 200 KB) into a Base64 String?

I need to know how to do it with Android, because I have to add the functionality to upload images to a remote server in my main app, putting them into a row of the database, as a string.

I am searching in Google and in Stack Overflow, but I could not find easy examples that I can afford and also I find some examples, but they are not talking about to transform into a String. Then I need to transform into a string to upload by JSON to my remote server.

Answer (score 368, accepted):

You can use the Base64 Android class:

```
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

You'll have to convert your image into a byte array though. Here's an example:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/to/image.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); // bm is the bitmap object
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```

*** Update ***

If you're using an older SDK library (because you want it to work on phones with older versions of the OS) you won't have the Base64 class packaged in (since it just came out in API level 8 AKA version 2.2).

Check this article out for a workaround:

*[How to base64 encode decode Android](http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html)*

Comment: ok, and them i can put that String (encondedImage) into a remote database column with PHP+JSON ???? wich type haves to be the column of the database? VARCHAR?

Comment: Well, with VARCHAR you need to specify how big it'd be, so maybe TEXT would be better. Image could be any range of sizes...

Comment: Hi, i am testing it but it gives me ERROR in Base64. It can't gind the class. I make Ctrl +shift+O to get the imports but doesn't gets imports... ¿how to solve it?

Comment: Class comes bundled with the SDK, so it should be there. You using Eclipse?

Comment: yes, im using it, and android SDK. Im programming for android 1.5..... eclipse tell me: Base64 cannot be resolved     and doesn't give me the possibility to import it

Comment: That's odd - seems to import it fine on mine. Add this as the import: `import android.util.Base64;`

Comment: ohhh f*ck, "Base64 works Since Api level 8, Android 2.2"...... my app have to be compatible with all versions of android... 1.5, 1.6, 2.1 etc...  can i do something to use Base64 on android 1.5 (api level 3) ???

Comment: Ah, yea you're right. This article should address that very problem: `http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html`. Also updated that in the answer.

Comment: ok ok , solved withat that Base64 external java!!! it works! now i can upload a photo in string format to my database. OK, but now, please, can yoy tell me how to transform that String into a photo BitMap again?

Comment: This approach works, but consumes a lot more memory than I would have thought necessary: my program crashes when I try to load a 3mb file as a bitmap.  (Come on, how big is a 3mb jpeg as a bitmap? 10mb? 30?)

Comment: For me was working after replacing:

String encodedImage = Base64.encode(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
By:

String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);

Comment: Does anybody realize that this method makes a meaningless recompress of the file?? why is this so upvoted?? Chandra Sekhar's answer is the most efficient.

Comment: ElYeante - you're absolutely right, that's a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: this is confusing. the method is called "decodeFile" and it does not accept a file as a parameter. great

Comment: This code is 70 - 80% ok, but its also requires your own efforts.

Comment: what if i want to use Base64 for multiple images. how do i do that?

Comment: Will there be an out of memory error for large images? Example 15MB images. If yes, what is the preferable size?

Answer (score 112):

Instead of using `Bitmap`, you can also do this through a trivial `InputStream`. Well, I am not sure, but I think it's a bit efficient.

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName); // You can get an inputStream using any I/O API
byte[] bytes;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int bytesRead;
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try {
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

bytes = output.toByteArray();
String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Of course this is more efficient; just transforms a file into its base64 representation, and avoids an absolutely meaningless recompression of the image.

Comment: is the fileName here the path of the file or the actual file name ??? Please don't forget to tag me :) Thanks.

Comment: @user2247689 When you are trying to access a file obviously you have to give the complete path of the file including its name. If the file is present in the same path where your source program is present, then file name is enough.

Comment: A question, what does '8192' signifies here, is it file size or what?

Comment: @DeveshKhandelwal, its the buffer size, not the file size.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! That said, I'm noticing that while working on Nexus devices (Nexus 6P and Nexus 5), it's not working on HTC One and Samsung Galaxy S5. Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: this code is not working, wasted many hours of mine to addess the issue.

Comment: Re *"a bit efficient"*: Do you mean *"a bit [inefficient](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inefficient#Adjective)"* (respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17874349/63550), not here in comments - as appropriate)?

Answer (score 8):

If you need Base64 over JSON, check out [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes): it has explicit support for binary data read/write as Base64 at both the low level (JsonParser, JsonGenerator) and data-binding level. So you can just have [POJOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) with byte[] properties, and encoding/decoding is automatically handled.

And pretty efficiently too, should that matter.

Comment: too hard for me, my skills are very low with this, i checked it on google and can't find easy examples... maybe if you can give me code examples like xil3 i will understand it

Answer (score 6):

Here is the encoding and decoding code in Kotlin:

```
 fun encode(imageUri: Uri): String {
    val input = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri)
    val image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input , null, null)

    // Encode image to base64 string
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
    var imageBytes = baos.toByteArray()
    val imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)
    return imageString
}

fun decode(imageString: String) {

    // Decode base64 string to image
    val imageBytes = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT)
    val decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)

    imageview.setImageBitmap(decodedImage)
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you close any opened inputstreams?

Answer (score 5):

```
// Put the image file path into this method
public static String getFileToByte(String filePath){
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
    byte[] bt = null;
    String encodeString = null;
    try{
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
        bt = bos.toByteArray();
        encodeString = Base64.encodeToString(bt, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encodeString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code runs perfect in my project:

```
profile_image.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = profile_image.getDrawingCache();
String encodedImageData = getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(bmap);


public String getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
    byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();

    // Get the Base64 string
    String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);

    return imgString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing this on **Android**, here's a helper copied from the [React Native codebase](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/9ee815f6b52e0c2417c04e5a05e1e31df26daed2/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/camera/ImageStoreManager.java):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Base64OutputStream;
import android.util.Log;

// You probably don't want to do this with large files
// (will allocate a large string and can cause an OOM crash).
private String readFileAsBase64String(String path) {
  try {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Base64OutputStream b64os = new Base64OutputStream(baos, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    try {
      while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) > -1) {
        b64os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
      }
      return baos.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Cannot read file " + path, e);
      // Or throw if you prefer
      return "";
    } finally {
      closeQuietly(is);
      closeQuietly(b64os); // This also closes baos
    }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "File not found " + path, e);
    // Or throw if you prefer
    return "";
  }
}

private static void closeQuietly(Closeable closeable) {
  try {
    closeable.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
  }
}
```

Comment: (will allocate a large string and can cause an OOM crash) So What is the solution in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Convert an image to Base64 string in Android:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourimage);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for an efficient method to convert an image file to a Base64 string without compression or converting the file to a bitmap first, you can instead [encode the file as base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28758014/how-to-convert-a-file-to-base64)

```
val base64EncodedImage = FileInputStream(imageItem.localSrc).use {inputStream - >
    ByteArrayOutputStream().use {outputStream - >
            Base64OutputStream(outputStream, Base64.DEFAULT).use {
                base64FilterStream - >
                    inputStream.copyTo(base64FilterStream)
                base64FilterStream.flush()
                outputStream.toString()
            }
      }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version:

```
fun File.toBase64(): String? {
 val result: String?
 inputStream().use { inputStream ->
    val sourceBytes = inputStream.readBytes()
    result = Base64.encodeToString(sourceBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)
 }

 return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of writing in Kotlin, simpler:

```
fun imageBase64(filepath: String): String {
    FileInputStream(filepath).use {
        val bytes = it.readBytes()
        return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(result.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the pseudocode that may help you:

```
public  String getBase64FromFile(String path)
{
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    byte[] baat = null;
    String encodeString = null;
    try
    {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        baat = baos.toByteArray();
        encodeString = Base64.encodeToString(baat, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   return encodeString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for image encoding and image decoding.

In an XML file

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="yyuyuyuuyuyuyu"
    android:id="@+id/tv5"
/>
```

In a Java file:

```
TextView textView5;
Bitmap bitmap;

textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv5);

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);

new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
        byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();

        // Get the Base64 string
        String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);

        return imgString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
       textView5.setText(s);
    }
}.execute();
```

Comment: Will this actually compile? Did you leave something out?

Answer (score 0):

I make a static function. Its more efficient i think.

```
public static String file2Base64(String filePath) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        String base64String = "";
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 100];
            int count = 0;
            while ((count = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        base64String = Base64.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        return base64String;

    }
```

Simple and easier!

Comment: it is adding next line to the string, can we overcome this?

Comment: getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/1417462683.jpg (No such file or directory) even if file path is correct

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin You can just use decode function for byteArray...

```
  private fun stringToBitmap(encodedString: String): Bitmap {
    val imageBytes = decode(encodedString, DEFAULT)
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for encode

```
 private String encodeImage(Bitmap bitmap){
        int previewWidth=150;
        int previewHeight=bitmap.getHeight()*previewWidth/ bitmap.getWidth();
        Bitmap previewBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,previewWidth,previewHeight,false);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        previewBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] bytes=byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(bytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
    }


private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> pickImage=registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode()==RESULT_OK){
                if (result.getData()!=null){
                    Uri imageuri=result.getData().getData();
                    try{
                        InputStream inputStream= getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageuri);
                        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                        binding.imageProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        encodedImage= encodeImage(bitmap);
                    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this code:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(Base64String.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Comment: This is just the opposite