# Bitmap to String using Base64. How can fix it?

Tags: android, image, base64, encode

The Base64.encode doesn't want to take the argument "image", and I don't know how to figure out. I've never used Base64 before.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
                    byte[] image = baos.toByteArray();

                    String encodedImage = Base64.encode(image);
```

Edit: I use an external package of Base64 http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a image into Base64 string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Base64 encode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) takes at least two arguments. Perhaps try `Base64.encode(image, Base64.DEFAULT)`

Comment: "The method encode(ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer) in the type Base64 is not applicable for the arguments (byte[], String)" I try to convert to ByteBuffer but there is still a problem...It seems pretty simple but I'm stuck like a noob.

Comment: There is no method encode(ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer) on android.util.Base64. As you sure you're using the android Base64 implementation?

Comment: I downloaded a Base64 package to make an application for all the versions of Android. Android.util.Base64 is available only after 2.2 version of android.

Comment: Perhaps you should update your original questions to let people know what Base64 package you're using.

Comment: Shame on me, I looked the wrong doc...the answer was encodeBytes.