# Send a Picture or Image to php Server

Tags: android, image, http, upload

I need to know the BEST way to load a bitmap and send it via http as a string, because i want to store it in a database. So could you help me with any ideas, please?

Thanks in advance, Regards

I had something this:

```
public byte[] ConvertBitmaptoBits(Bitmap src) 
{
    try{
        ByteArrayOutputStream os=new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
        src.compress( android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, (OutputStream)os );

        src.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os); //bm is the bitmap object   
        byte[] b = os.toByteArray();
        return b;
    }catch(Throwable e)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Error en ConvierteBitmapAString: " + e.getMessage(), 30);
        Log.v("ConvierteBitmapACadena", "Error al Convertir la imagen a Cadena: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }           
}
```

In my SEND method i had something like this:

```
public void Send() //throws Exception
{
    try 
    {
        InputStreamBody isb=null;
        StringBody sImageString=null;

        Resources r = this.getResources();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, R.drawable.icon);
    byte[] objImageBits = ConvertBitmaptoBits(bmp);


        if(objImageBits !=null ){
            isb     = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(objImageBits), "uploadedFile");
        }

        HttpClient httpClient   = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost postRequest    = new HttpPost(strPath);

        SimpleDateFormat sdfDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String strCurDate =  sdfDateTime.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));


        StringBody sCurDate     = new StringBody(strCurDate);

        MultipartEntity multipartContent = new MultipartEntity();
        if(objImageBits !=null)
        {
            multipartContent.addPart("uploadedFile", isb);
        }
        multipartContent.addPart("fechaequipo", sCurDate);          
        postRequest.setEntity(multipartContent);


        HttpResponse response   = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        Log.v("executeMultipartPost", "Error in executeMultipartPost: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But it seems i am not getting the uploadedFile.  This is my php script:

```
$file2           = (isset($_POST['uploadedFile'])) ? ( $_POST['uploadedFile'] ):('');

$fechaequipo    = (isset($_POST['fechaequipo']) ) ? ( $_POST['fechaequipo'] ):('');

$fp = null;
$log_file = 'log.txt';

if (!$fp) 
    $fp = fopen($log_file, 'a') or exit("No se puede abrir: $log_file!");

fwrite($fp, "<INI LOG>" . date("d/m/Y") ."\n\r");

fwrite($fp, "Date   : ". $fechaequipo . "\n\r");

fwrite($fp, "File2 : " . $file2 . "\n\r");

fwrite($fp, "<END LOG>" . date("d/m/Y") ."\n\r");
fclose($fp);
```

?>

Do I'm doing anything wrong? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

A similar question (in a sense) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string).

You convert you image to base64, then send to a server however you like. The server can then decode the string to an image. (With PHP, that'd be [`base64-decode`](http://php.net/base64-decode)).

Bear in mind that base64 encoding increases the size of the data transferred by [about 33%](http://php.net/base64-encode).