# Encrypt and decrypt data for Android app-client

Tags: android, encryption

With this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
I convert an image into a String.
Now I want to encrypt this string before send the data in server. Is there a simple way to encrypt and decrypt the string?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319496/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-data-in-java) question?

Comment: try this http://viswanathl.in/2014/01/encryption-and-decryption-using-aes-in-android/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**javax.crypto**

This package provides the classes and interfaces for cryptographic applications implementing algorithms for encryption, decryption, or key agreement.

Stream ciphers are supported as well as asymmetric, symmetric and block ciphers. Cipher implementations from different providers can be integrated using the SPI (Service Provider Interface) abstract classes. With class SealedObject a programmer can secure an object by encrypting it with a cipher.

Authentication may be based on MAC (Message Authentication Code) such as HMAC (Hash MAC, i.e. with a SHA-1 hash function).

**Example:**

Simple helper class to encrypt and decrypt strings using AES128. The result is Ascii-encoded (actually hex, no base64), so no byte[] has to be stored. A SEED value is used as a shared secret ("Master-Password"). Only with the same SEED the stored values can be decrypted.

```
package com.xxx;

import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
 * Usage:
 * <pre>
 * String crypto = SimpleCrypto.encrypt(masterpassword, cleartext)
 * ...
 * String cleartext = SimpleCrypto.decrypt(masterpassword, crypto)
 * </pre>
 * @author ferenc.hechler
 */
public class SimpleCrypto {

    public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
        return toHex(result);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
        return new String(result);
    }

    private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");
        sr.setSeed(seed);
        kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
        return raw;
    }


    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
        return encrypted;
    }

    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }

    public static String toHex(String txt) {
        return toHex(txt.getBytes());
    }
    public static String fromHex(String hex) {
        return new String(toByte(hex));
    }

    public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
        int len = hexString.length()/2;
        byte[] result = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
        return result;
    }

    public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
        if (buf == null)
            return "";
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            appendHex(result, buf[i]);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
        sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
    }

}
```

For more info look at [Android Security
How to encrypt and decrypt strings?](http://www.tutorials-android.com/learn/How_to_encrypt_and_decrypt_strings.rhtml) and [Encryption on Android & BouncyCastle](http://www.unwesen.de/2011/06/12/encryption-on-android-bouncycastle/)

Comment: I'm getting "BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted" on the decrypt method. Encryption works ok.

Comment: Getting BadPaddingException too. Any solution?

Comment: Getting BadPaddingException too. Any solution?

Comment: To fix **"BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted"** you should specify provider when getting instance of SecureRandom, so in this case: `SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SecureCredentialsCrypto {

            public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
                    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
                    byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
                    return toHex(result);
            }

            public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
                    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
                    byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
                    byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
                    return new String(result);
            }

            private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
                    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
                    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
                    sr.setSeed(seed);
                kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
                SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
                byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
                return raw;
            }


            private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
                SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
                byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
                    return encrypted;
            }

            private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
                SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
                byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
                    return decrypted;
            }

            public static String toHex(String txt) {
                    return toHex(txt.getBytes());
            }
            public static String fromHex(String hex) {
                    return new String(toByte(hex));
            }

            public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
                    int len = hexString.length()/2;
                    byte[] result = new byte[len];
                    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
                    return result;
            }

            public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
                    if (buf == null)
                            return "";
                    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
                    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
                            appendHex(result, buf[i]);
                    }
                    return result.toString();
            }
            private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
                    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
            }

    }

//for storing encrypt it
String crypto_email = SecureCredentialsCrypto.encrypt("secure", email.toString().trim());

//for reading  decrypt it
//crypto is object name to read 


String correctEmail=SecureCredentialsCrypto.decrypt("secure", crypto);
```

Comment: Getting BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.duplicate;



   public class RSAEncryptionDescription {


 private static final String PUBLIC_KEY_FILE = "Public.key";  
 private static final String PRIVATE_KEY_FILE = "Private.key";  

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  

  try {  
   System.out.println("-------GENRATE PUBLIC and PRIVATE KEY-------------");  
   KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");  
   keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048); //1024 used for normal securities  
   KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();  
   PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();  
   PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();  
   System.out.println("Public Key - " + publicKey);  
   System.out.println("Private Key - " + privateKey);

   //Pullingout parameters which makes up Key  
   System.out.println("\n------- PULLING OUT PARAMETERS WHICH MAKES KEYPAIR----------\n");  
   KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");  
   RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(publicKey, RSAPublicKeySpec.class);  
   RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPrivKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(privateKey, RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);  
   System.out.println("PubKey Modulus : " + rsaPubKeySpec.getModulus());  
   System.out.println("PubKey Exponent : " + rsaPubKeySpec.getPublicExponent());  
   System.out.println("PrivKey Modulus : " + rsaPrivKeySpec.getModulus());  
   System.out.println("PrivKey Exponent : " + rsaPrivKeySpec.getPrivateExponent());  

   //Share public key with other so they can encrypt data and decrypt thoses using private key(Don't share with Other)  
   System.out.println("\n--------SAVING PUBLIC KEY AND PRIVATE KEY TO FILES-------\n");  
   RSAEncryptionDescription rsaObj = new RSAEncryptionDescription();  
   rsaObj.saveKeys(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE, rsaPubKeySpec.getModulus(), rsaPubKeySpec.getPublicExponent());  
   rsaObj.saveKeys(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE, rsaPrivKeySpec.getModulus(), rsaPrivKeySpec.getPrivateExponent());  

   //Encrypt Data using Public Key  
   byte[] encryptedData = rsaObj.encryptData("Anuj Patel - Classified Information !");  

   //Descypt Data using Private Key  
   rsaObj.decryptData(encryptedData);  

  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
  }catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
  }  

 }  

 /** 
  * Save Files 
  * @param fileName 
  * @param mod 
  * @param exp 
  * @throws IOException 
  */  
 private void saveKeys(String fileName,BigInteger mod,BigInteger exp) throws IOException{  
  FileOutputStream fos = null;  
  ObjectOutputStream oos = null;  

  try {  
   System.out.println("Generating "+fileName + "...");  
   fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);  
   oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));  

   oos.writeObject(mod);  
   oos.writeObject(exp);     

   System.out.println(fileName + " generated successfully");  
  } catch (Exception e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
  }  
  finally{  
   if(oos != null){  
    oos.close();  

    if(fos != null){  
     fos.close();  
    }  
   }  
  }    
 }  

 /** 
  * Encrypt Data 
  * @param data 
  * @throws IOException 
  */  
 private byte[] encryptData(String data) throws IOException {  
  System.out.println("\n----------------ENCRYPTION STARTED------------");  

  System.out.println("Data Before Encryption :" + data);  
  byte[] dataToEncrypt = data.getBytes();  
  byte[] encryptedData = null;  
  try {  
   PublicKey pubKey = readPublicKeyFromFile(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE);  
   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");  
   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);  
   encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt);  
   System.out.println("Encryted Data: " + encryptedData);  

  } catch (Exception e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
  }   

  System.out.println("----------------ENCRYPTION COMPLETED------------");    
  return encryptedData;  
 }  

 /** 
  * Encrypt Data 
  * @param data 
  * @throws IOException 
  */  
 private void decryptData(byte[] data) throws IOException {  
  System.out.println("\n----------------DECRYPTION STARTED------------");  
  byte[] descryptedData = null;  

  try {  
   PrivateKey privateKey = readPrivateKeyFromFile(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE);  
   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");  
   cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);  
   descryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data);  
   System.out.println("Decrypted Data: " + new String(descryptedData));  

  } catch (Exception e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
  }   

  System.out.println("----------------DECRYPTION COMPLETED------------");    
 }  

 /** 
  * read Public Key From File 
  * @param fileName 
  * @return PublicKey 
  * @throws IOException 
  */  
 public PublicKey readPublicKeyFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException{  
  FileInputStream fis = null;  
  ObjectInputStream ois = null;  
  try {  
   fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));  
   ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);  

   BigInteger modulus = (BigInteger) ois.readObject();  
      BigInteger exponent = (BigInteger) ois.readObject();  

      //Get Public Key  
      RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);  
      KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");  
      PublicKey publicKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPublicKeySpec);  

      return publicKey;  

  } catch (Exception e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
  }  
  finally{  
   if(ois != null){
    ois.close();  
    if(fis != null){
     fis.close();
    }
   }  
  }  
  return null;  
 }  

 /** 
  * read Public Key From File 
  * @param fileName 
  * @return 
  * @throws IOException 
  */  
 public PrivateKey readPrivateKeyFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException{  
  FileInputStream fis = null;  
  ObjectInputStream ois = null;  
  try {  
   fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));  
   ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);  

   BigInteger modulus = (BigInteger) ois.readObject();  
      BigInteger exponent = (BigInteger) ois.readObject();  

      //Get Private Key  
      RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPrivateKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, exponent);  
      KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");  
      PrivateKey privateKey = fact.generatePrivate(rsaPrivateKeySpec);  

      return privateKey;  

  } catch (Exception e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
  }  
  finally{  
   if(ois != null){  
    ois.close();  
    if(fis != null){  
     fis.close();  
    }  
   }  
  }  
  return null;  
 }  
}
```