# How to crypt and decrypt the given edit text value in android?

Tags: java, android, encryption

Hi I want to encrypt and decrypt the given edit text value in my application. I completed encryption. But the encryption value is too long. My code is:

```
  import java.security.MessageDigest;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class EncodeAndDEcode extends Activity 
  {
TextView txt,encry,decry;
TextView encrypt_txt,decrypt_txt;
Button encrypt_but,decrypt_but;
EditText text;
String my_text="";
static String myString1="";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    encry=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    decry=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    encrypt_txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);
    decrypt_txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv5);

    text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);

    decrypt_but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    encrypt_but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt2);


    encrypt_but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            System.out.println("Encrypt button has been clicked");
            my_text=text.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("My string is---> "+my_text);

          // myEncrypt(my_text);
          encrypt_txt.setText(myEncrypt(my_text));


        }
    });  


    decrypt_but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            System.out.println("Decrypt button has been clicked");


        }
    });

}




public static String myEncrypt(String data1)
{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try 
    {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        messageDigest.update(data1.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] digestBytes = messageDigest.digest();

        String hex = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < digestBytes.length; i++) 
        {
            hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & digestBytes[i]);
            if (hex.length() < 2) 
                sb.append("0");
            sb.append(hex);
            }
       myString1 = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(myString1);
        }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
   return new String(sb);
} }
```

I got the encrypt value like this

```
  da7b83206f136b263d2cf0ff968aa6301bdc002101e4dd980832411b67cb54cfcb9e862c8f3344abb72741c2312b84b562d623676b2af49913f486f1b4cef73a
```

Now I want to decrypt this encryption. How can i do this? Can anybody suggest the best way of encryption and decrypt ion in android? Can anybody help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397213/encrypt-and-decrypt-data-for-android-app-client/8397465#8397465

Comment: That's not an encryption. It's a hashing algorithm. Hash algorithms are designed to be be non-reversible... take a look at AES, DES, etc. not SHA or MD5.. ;)

Comment: I see AES encryption in the link shared by Padma Kumar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your code I see that you are using `SHA` for encrypting the `String`.
`SHA` is a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). As coding.mof rightly pointed out that you can't really `decrypt`the string `encrypted` using `SHA` as it is `non-reversible`.
If you need to encrypt something and later decrypt it, you need to use something like `AES` or `RSA` or may be `DES` depending upon what are comfortable with.

Here are few links to get you started :

1) [Link 1](http://www.tutorials-android.com/learn/How_to_encrypt_and_decrypt_strings.rhtml)

2) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220761/fast-and-simple-string-encrypt-decrypt-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I found some examples in the following link
http://www.tutorials-android.com/learn/How_to_encrypt_and_decrypt_strings.rhtml

Comment: link appears to be dead, at least for me.