# Encrypting only specific tables / fields of an SQLite database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Is it possible?

I read about SQLCipher, but it seems to encrypt the whole database.

Is there a way to configure it to encrypt only specific parts of it?

A table or a field will do just fine.

Comment: Android is quite secure regarding SQLite. From what do you want to keep data encrypted?

Comment: Why not encrypt the whole database? I've used SQLCipher it's pretty quick. The only downside is it adds 4MB to .apk size

Comment: I just want to store the app client's ID and secret provided by Facebook securely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I didn't need to use SQLite or any other techniques for encryption, because I found out I don't have to store the app client's secret at all, just the ID which is public.

Answer (score 0):

You could use expand the DBHelper and run certain queries through a simple encryption util like the one noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397213/encrypt-and-decrypt-data-for-android-app-client).

Or rip out the [CrypoHelper](http://code.google.com/p/android-passwordsafe/source/browse/branches/crypto-refactor/src/com/bitsetters/android/passwordsafe/CryptoHelper.java?r=59) from [android-passwordsafe](http://code.google.com/p/android-passwordsafe/) written by Steven Osborn.