# Encrypting and decrypting data in android

Tags: android, encryption

I am saving user's credentials in my app for some purpose. I have to encrypt the data before saving it in to preferences. I have gone through different tutorials and links. But got confused. Can you please help me?

Comment: use any encryption methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788018/android-encryption-decryption-with-aes and      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397213/encrypt-and-decrypt-data-for-android-app-client

Answer (score -1):

Well why don't you create your own encryption function with your own logic which is difficult to break? The library too gonna do the same thing  for you

Comment: I have no idea about this. This is the first time i am doing encryption.