# Encrypt A String and make it secure even apk is extracted

Tags: php, android, encryption, apk, reverse-engineering

I want to save an unique **String as variable in encrypted form** and pass the variable as parameter to my PHP server in each request so that I can be sure that the request is coming from my android application not from other browsers..

I don't want others know my String even If my apk is extracted or became victim of reverse engineering. 
Is there any way to store a variable Like that way in encrypted form.

It would be helpful if you mention a process to Decrypt same variable with PHP.. 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397213/encrypt-and-decrypt-data-for-android-app-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Encrypt A String and secure even apk is extracted

The only way to accomplish the question in the title is to use asymmetric cryptography (i.e. [crypto_box_seal](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/08-advanced.md#crypto-box-seal), which prevents the Android device from ever decrypting it).

> so that I can be sure that the request is coming from my android application not from other browsers.

Impossible. Anyone can create a client that emulates your APK.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. It was so helpful but I want to accomplish these kind of task to my android application not in php. I didn't meant that the string is to be prevented from android device.
Android application can easily be extracted and source code can be seen. so I want to prevent the hacker from seeing my string value of the variable... anyway thanks again