# Image Upload Using .net Webservices

Tags: android, web-services, image

I am Developing an `Android` Based Application. I am Using `.net webservice` to upload the data. Here I am successfully able to upload all the data except Image Byes. I want to know how to send Image as Binary array to the `.net webservice`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can convert images in the `Base64` string and then its easy to upload string on the server.

Just check this question for code of [Converting image to Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string)

Comment: can you give me any example site for it please ?

Comment: You have already mentioned that you are successful to upload all the data, then why do you require an example site? Just convert the image into string and upload the string.