# Sending Image to server in android

Tags: android

In android I am trying to send image to the server.I am using Multipart request. But when I add image in format ByteArray to the Multipart UnsupportedEncodingException occurs.
following is my code.
 Do I need to add mime type to request.
 If possible please post the complete Sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done it with the use of MultiPartEntity . Added image as byteArrayBody and done the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the Image to Base64 format string and then sending that string to the server.
Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string) to convert image to base64 format.

And then at server end decode it.