# Android image upload using base64

Tags: android, android-listview

I am working with images on edit profile page... in my android application. I am having trouble in converting image to base64 code... so help me to store and retrive images on my database... and I am using cake php & php myadmin.

Comment: [How to convert a image into Base64 string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string)

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
public String getBase64String(Bitmap photoBitmap) {
    String photo;
    if (photoBitmap != null) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photoBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bao);
        // photoBitmap.recycle();
        photo = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bao.toByteArray(),
                android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        try {
            bao.close();
            bao = null;
            photoBitmap = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        photo = "";
    }
    return photo;
}
```