# Sending image in android studio

Tags: android, image, google-cloud-messaging

I am currently developing one application that allow user to send report of any job. Beside this i want to send also a image of work. 
How to send image from sender to receiver in android studio OR which is the best way to implement this features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your report is probably one of most common type: XML or JSON, if its true, You can encode your image as Base64, and put that string into your report.

**EDIT**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string) you can find how to convert any image to Base64 String. That string you can put into your message as an variable.

Comment: Thanks Artur for fast respond, can u give me any example or link that i can have a look?