# android Convert images to base64 for php

Tags: android

The method of preparation Base64 format images To write a php server with a set of standard image size set size

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath), sizeW, sizeH, true)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a image into Base64 string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int sizeW=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath).getWidth();
int sizeH=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath).getHeight();
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0,sizeW, sizeH), new RectF(0, 0, 300, 100), Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath), 0, 0, sizeW, sizeH, m, true);

//Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath), sizeW, sizeH, true);

ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
//Log.d("size200",String.valueOf((bm.getByteCount()/1024)/2));
ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);
Log.e("base64-1", "-----" + ba1);
```

**AsyncTask Class:**

```
   public class uploadToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(RegisterAds.this);
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd.setMessage("send");
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
     protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("base64", ba1));
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String st = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.v("log_tag", "In the try Loop" + st);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
            return "Success";

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.hide();
            Log.d("nameimage", String.valueOf(name_image_upload_i1));
            new SummaryAsyncTask().execute((Void) null);
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

use:

```
 new uploadToServer().execute();
```

php code:

```
    <?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_POST['ImageName'])){
$imgname = $_POST['ImageName'];
$imsrc = base64_decode($_POST['base64']);
$save_path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/news/upload/".$imgname;  //.$data;
header("Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8");
$fp = fopen($save_path, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $imsrc);
if(fclose($fp)){
echo "Image uploaded";
}else{
echo "Error uploading image";}}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// method for bitmap to base64
    public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
        Bitmap immage = image;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        immage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return imageEncoded;

    }
```