# sending Attachments using Mandrill api in android

Tags: android, email, email-attachments, mandrill

I am using `Mandrill` App to send emails from my android application. I am trying to send emails with attachment. But I am unable to send attachments. As per requirement I have converted image file and text file into base64 string and passed to json object of mandrill api. But still mail goes without attachment. I referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string) to convert image file to into base64. I also want to attach Doc, Ppts, Pdfs to attachment. If anyone knows please guide me.

Comment: Did you see this? http://thenextweb.com/dd/2016/02/25/in-hostile-move-mandrill-gives-all-developers-60-days-to-switch-to-paid-mailchimp-service/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this [link](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send) you will need to fill in the the Attachments Array. Here is the relevant JSON part:

```
"attachments": [
        {
            "type": "text/plain",
            "name": "myfile.txt",
            "content": "ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl"
        }
    ],
```

Other services like SparkPost also provide an easy way to do this too. The reason I bring up SparkPost is this post from Mandrill CEO: http://blog.mailchimp.com/important-changes-to-mandrill/

Comment: Actually I I have added all the contents of this array. Now Image file is going as attachment but it is received as damaged image.

Comment: If you base64 decode the `content` field is it a good file. Try on the output and on the receive side. Beware not to take binary through UTF8 or something like that . You will want the raw bytes.

Comment: Actually I am not decoding it at receiver side, Receiver side is any mail client or site like gmail, yahoo or outlook @Yepher

Comment: Sorry, I was just thinking about a test too see where it goes wrong. My suspicion is that the sending side base64 encoding it not correct. At least that is where I've got bit before.