# How to upload image with string data using android studio to mysql server

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, android-studio

I am new to android studio. I am developing apps and website. The apps for capture image, website for admin. The apps activity involves capture image, detect location, detect timedate, insert name, insert comment.

The problem is when I want to upload image together with data location, timedate, name and comment to my server MySQL it's not working.

Here is my coding on php:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "hafiza", "98765432i", "trackerproject");

    $rid = $_POST["rid"]
    $rname = $_POST["rname"];
    $rimage = $_POST["rimage"];
    $rlocation = $_POST["rlocation"];
    $rdate = $_POST["rdate"];
    $rcomment = $_POST["rcomment"];
    $rstatus = $_POST["rstatus"];

    $statement ="SELECT rid FROM report ORDER BY rid ASC";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$statement);
    $rid = 0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $rid = $row['rid'];
    }

    $path = "uploads/$id.png";

    $actualpath = "http://hafizahusairi.com/trackerproject/$path";

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO report (rname, rimage, rlocation, rdate, rcomment, rstatus) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?='New',)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssssss", $rname, $rimage, $rlocation, $rdate, $rcomment, $rstatus);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    if(mysqli_query($con,$statement)){
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($rimage));
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
    }else{
    echo "Error";

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

---

Here is my android studio coding.

```
package com.hafizahusairi.cameratracker;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

public class Display extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    //location
    static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    //Date and Time
    Calendar calander;
    SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat;

    EditText etTimeDate;
    Button btnDateTime;

    private Button bSelectPhoto;
    private Button bReportSubmit;

    private ImageView ivDisplayImage;
    private EditText etLocation;
    private EditText etName;
    private EditText etComment;

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    private String UPLOAD_URL ="http://hafizahusairi.com/trackerproject/photoUpload/upload.php";


    private String rdate = "rdate";
    private String rname = "rname";
    private String rimage = "rimage";
    private String rlocation = "rlocation";
    private String rcomment = "rcomment";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

        //button
        bSelectPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSelectPhoto);
        bReportSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bReportSubmit);
        btnDateTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDateTime);

        ivDisplayImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivDisplayImage);
        etLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLocation);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etComment);

        //button onclick
        bSelectPhoto.setOnClickListener(this);
        bReportSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

        etTimeDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTimeDate);

        //Location
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        getLocation();


        calander = Calendar.getInstance();
        simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy , HH:mm:ss");
        rdate = simpledateformat.format(calander.getTime());
        btnDateTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                etTimeDate.setText(rdate);

            }
        });


    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }


    //tak dapat upload image dengan string params
    private void uploadImage(){
        //Showing the progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Uploading...","Please wait...",false,false);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        //Disimissing the progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();
                        //Showing toast message of the response
                        Toast.makeText(Display.this, s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        //Dismissing the progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();

                        //Showing toast
                        Toast.makeText(Display.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                //Converting Bitmap to String
                String rimage = getStringImage(bitmap);

                //Getting Image Name
                String rname = etName.getText().toString().trim();
                String rlocation = etLocation.getText().toString().trim();
                String rdate = etTimeDate.getText().toString().trim();
                String rcomment = etComment.getText().toString().trim();

                //Creating parameters
                Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                //Adding parameters
                params.put(rname, rname);
                params.put(rimage, rimage);
                params.put(rlocation, rlocation);
                params.put(rdate, rdate);
                params.put(rcomment, rcomment);

                //returning parameters
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Creating a Request Queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    //select image dah OK!
    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                ivDisplayImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



    //detect location dah OK!
    void getLocation() {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
        } else {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (location != null) {
                double latti = location.getLatitude();
                double longi = location.getLongitude();

                ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.etLocation)).setText(latti + "," + longi);
            } else {
                ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.etLocation)).setText("Unable to find current location. Try again");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_LOCATION:
                getLocation();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v == bSelectPhoto){
            showFileChooser();
        }

        if(v == bReportSubmit){
            uploadImage();
        }
    }
}
```

---

my database looks like:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a image into Base64 string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string)

Answer (score 0):

for save image to server you must get bitmap of your image and convert bitmap to string and send string to server , and from server save it with this function

`file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($image));`

function that return string of image :

```
private String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

send image and other parameter like this :

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
            Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            params.put("image", image);
            params.put("title", title);
            params.put("description", description);
            return params;
        }
```