# VolleyError: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-volley

Good Day, I am getting:

> com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a
>   null object reference

Here is my code

```
     private void volleyImageUpload(String url)
    {
        Log.d("safasf",lat+ ""+lon);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PictureCommentActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading data Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        //converting image to base64 string
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//        Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 500, 500);
//        Bitmap scaledBitmap = scaleDown(bitmap, 800, true);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
//        long lengthbmp = imageBytes.length;
        final String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

        Log.v("base 64 == ",imageString);

        //sending image to server
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Log.d("Respo",s);
                // popup
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
                    if(object.getString("status").equals("0"))
                    {
                        ShowMessage.msg(PictureCommentActivity.this, ""+object.getString("status_message"));

                    }
                    else{
                        showConfirmMessage("Congratulations","You Have Successfully Uploaded the Post");

//                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
//                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        },new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
//               Log.d("Respo",volleyError+"");
//                Toast.makeText(PictureCommentActivity.this, ""+volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                progressDialog.dismiss();
//                showConfirmMessage("Unfortunately","Your Internet Connection is Weak please try Again");


                if(volleyError!=null && volleyError.getMessage() !=null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error VOLLEY "+volleyError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        }) {
            //adding parameters to send
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parameters.put("img", imageString);
                parameters.put("lat", lat);
                parameters.put("lng", lon);
                parameters.put("org_id", org);
                parameters.put("user_id", id);
                parameters.put("usertype",user_type);
                parameters.put("cmmt", comments.getText().toString());

                return parameters;
            }
        };
//        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000,  0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, -1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        rQueue.add(request);
    }
```

I have try so many way but didnt find any solution i know this is the common question in stack overflow but that ans won.t help me

MY bitmap code

```
    int targetW = image.getWidth();
        int targetH = image.getHeight();

        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        Log.d("Respo","targetH "+targetH + "\ntargetW "+targetW + "\nphotoW"+photoW+"\nphotoH"+photoH);
        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);
        Log.d("Respo","scaleFactor "+scaleFactor );

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

         bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

//        Toast.makeText(this, ""+Build.MANUFACTURER, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if ("samsung".contentEquals(Build.MANUFACTURER))// &&
              //  getRequestedOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT) // && width > height//)
        {
//            Toast.makeText(this, "hii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            image.setRotation(90);
        }
```

MY LOGCAT 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aTji.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @akhilesh0707 Possibly duplicate but that solution did not help me

Comment: post your complete error log here

Comment: share the logcat error

Comment: @akhilesh0707 i have already mention my logcat error

Comment: @sumit i am getting this error message on a particular device not all every device

Comment: where is your bitmap?

Comment: `imageString` is null  try this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/4830846/1548824

Comment: did you comment `long lengthbmp = imageBytes.length;` this link after getting the error?

Comment: @akhilesh0707 now u can see my bitmap code , Apart from One device its working fine in all devices

Comment: @harsh what is the value of `Log.v("base 64 == ",imageString);`

Comment: @harsh if you don't mind can you post your complete error log here

Comment: @akhilesh0707 i am new here my reputation in not 10 so i wont be able to send image

Comment: @akhilesh0707 you can visit https://paste.ubuntu.com/25625220/

Comment: @harsh post your complete error log `java.lang.NullPointerException`