# How to convert Photo from the SD card to base64?

Tags: java, android, image, base64, sd-card

I wish to convert photo to base64, and the photo is from my external SD card. I have try out this code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_picture);

    File yourFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp/Hello.jpg");
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(yourFile));

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

    byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray();

    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.simpleTextView);

    textView.setText(encodedImage); //set text for text view

}
```

But in logcat show me **bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, baos);** have error, anyone can share me ideas?

logcat error:

[image]

Comment: [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4830846/8311908) it converts the image bitmap to base64 string

Comment: Please show complete logcat. You omitted the error message.

Comment: @greenapps hi i edit my post by adding the pic

Comment: Please post the logcat as text. No images please.

Comment: place your onActivityResult() code to your question

Comment: Ever heard of a `NullPointerException`? And how difficult is it to post the code that causes it?

Comment: Actually this code I only have, don't have any activityonresult