# how to store and retrieve images using sqlite in android studio manually

Tags: android, sqlite, camera

I am trying to save images in SQLite.I have created an app that takes a picture and compares it with saved images in SQLite.So how can I store images in SQLite?

I used BLOB data type for storing images

**NewAccount.java**

```
public void insertUserData()
    {


        /**
         * STUDENT DATABASER
         */

        ContentValues contentValues1 =  new ContentValues();
        contentValues1.put(LoginEntryStudent.STUDENT_COLUMN_ROLL_NO,"17121070");
        contentValues1.put(LoginEntryStudent.STUDENT_COLUMN_FIRST_NAME,"Gautam");
        contentValues1.put(LoginEntryStudent.STUDENT_COLUMN_LAST_NAME,"Helange");
        contentValues1.put(LoginEntryStudent.STUDENT_COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER,"7517424135");
        contentValues1.put(LoginEntryStudent.STUDENT_COLUMN_EMAIL_ID,"gautamhelange025@gmail.com");
        contentValues1.put(LoginEntryStudent.STUDENT_COLUMN_GENDER,LoginEntryStudent.STUDENT_GENDER_MALE);


        //what value put there so image will be save from my mobile gallery
        contentValues1.put(LoginEntryStudent.STUDENT_COLUMN_IMAGE,"what put here");

        Uri newUriStudent = getContentResolver().insert(LoginEntryStudent.CONTENT_URI_STUDENT,contentValues1);

        Intent i = new Intent(NewAccount.this,WelcomeApp.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your image into Base64 format then save into sqlite.

check the first answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string) link to know how to convert image into base64