# Transfer file from native and receive it in flutter

Tags: flutter, native

I have a kotlin app and I need to transfer an image file from native to flutter. I am new to the kotlin side but good with flutter. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2):

How about transfer image data in base64 string format,

In Kotlin side, encode the image file data into base64 format,

In Flutter side, decode the base64 string to image,

I think it is the normal way to transfer images or other files between different Languages

Comment: What should I write in Kotlin side I am new to it.

Comment: you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-a-base64-string