# How to save ImageView image in SharedPreference and display in other activity (Gridview)?

Tags: java, android

How do I save ImageView image in SharedPreference and display in other activity (Gridview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save Image in **SharedPreferences**, by converting the image to **Base64** format.

If you convert it, you would have an image in String format, that can be saved to **SharedPreferences** normally, and when you would like to retreive the image, you concert from **Base64** to **Bitmap**.

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-a-base64-string), I believe it will help you.

Comment: Without conversation it displayed in other activitythat problem is solved .. my question is how I can access that image to another activity gridview form

Comment: So, do you want to show this images in a gridview in another activity?

Comment: Yes sir .. I want to display those images in a gridview