# Get image from webservice .Net

Tags: android, web-services, image

I am creating application client-server on android,that server is webservice .net,Client is android app.On webservice containt database that table has field images.How to get image from websevice?plz,help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hi u can get and post images in adroid in the form of base64 encoding method.

see the following post in SO. u will get an idea. [converting base64 String to image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902560/converting-base64-string-to-image-in-android)