# Upload a base64 converted image on server in android

Tags: android, file-upload, base64

I need to convert the Image in base64 format and then upload it on server and then retrieve the base64 string from the server and convert it back to image... How to do it?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you have to [_expand_ an image by 33%](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding) when uploading? Seems counter-intuitive to me.

Answer (score 1):

First Convert Bitmap to Base 64

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap("Your Bitmap Object Here", 100, 100, false);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, false);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Then Upload with Json Object as Below:

```
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        String withBase = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + encoded;
        jsonObject.put("b64", "" + withBase);
        System.out.println("base 64 == " + jsonObject.toString());
        return jsonObject.toString();
```

Then You can retrieve these Base 64 string on Your Response.

And then Convert these Base64 to bitmap by Below:

byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

Then use these bitmap in Your Image View.

Answer (score 0):

This post was made by someone wanting to go the opposite direction you're going, but the answers are still relevant:

[converting base64 String to image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902560/converting-base64-string-to-image-in-android)

Beware of out of memory problems:

[OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget :- Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928002/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)

Here's an example of posting a file to a server from an Android app:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e51d4f74452a1143?tvc=2&pli=1

Answer (score 0):

Use this [link](http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/) and get the Base64Coder class . This will help you to Encode Image into Base64 String and Decode the String into byte array.You can make Image file by using that bytes.

```
    byte[] stringBytes = your_Base64_String.getBytes();
    byte[] img = null;
    try {
        img = Base64Coder.decode(stringBytes );
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String ConvertBitmapToBase64Format(Bitmap bitmap) 

   {

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
    byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
    // get the base 64 string
    String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    return imageString;

   }

   // then this imageString pass to json object 
   String encodedImage=ConvertBitmapToBase64Format(bitmap); // pass your image bitmap

   JsonObject.put("Key",
                    encodedImage);

   pass this jsonObject to your webservice
```